Random hashing, random boss
There are 100 pies and 100 students. They all have a favourite random pie (it may or may not be the same across students).
The students queue to pick their favourite pie (among the ones that remain available). I am interested in the probability that the $k$-th person in the queue gets his favourite pie.
Pr(1st picks top)=1
Pr(2nd picks top)=$(1-\frac{1}{n})$
Pr(3rd picks top)=$(1-\frac{1}{n}\frac{1}{n-1})$ (maybe not?)
Pr(4th picks top)=1-Pr(1 doesn't get my top) Pr(2 doesn't get my top) \Prob(3 doesn't get my top)=$1-\frac{1}{n}\frac{1}{n-1}\frac{1}{n-2}$
Pr($k$-th picks top)=very small, maybe $1-\sum_{i=0}^{k-2}1-\frac{1}{n-i}$
Any hints to see if I'm on the right path are appreciated. I am trying to add all those probabilities (I know the sum is not a probability!)
and which I am guessing looks like
$$1-\frac{n-1}{n}-\frac{n-2}{n-1}-\frac{n-3}{n-2}+\ldots$$

Assuming all the random preferences are independent, by the time the $k$th person gets to choose a pie, every possible set of $k-1$ pies is equally likely to be the set of pies already claimed. The probability that the $k$th person's favorite pie is not among those is $1-\frac{k-1}n$.
